# QTP UFT - how to select a value from the drop down in Excel

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to select a value from the drop down in excel by using QTP/UFT. Please help me with this issue.

[image]

Comment: See the answers provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232521/selecting-a-specific-item-from-dropdown-in-excel-vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a specific item from Dropdown in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232521/selecting-a-specific-item-from-dropdown-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you so much kira. It works